# only static members can be accessed in initializers in stepper widget

Tags: android, flutter

This is a flutter app using the stepper widget to display other widgets. I need to put two checkbox tile widgets in a row and which will be seperated by columns. I have initialized the checkbox tile widget but it keeps displaying a 'only static members can be accessed in initializers' for the onChanged and value parameters

```
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomeState createState() => new MyHomeState();
}

class MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {

  void onChanged(bool value){
    setState(() {
      _isChecked = value;
    });
  }
static bool _isChecked = false;

  // init the step to 0th position
  int current_step = 0;
  List<Step> my_steps = [
    new Step(
      // Title of the Step
        title: new Text("Residential Data"),
        // Content, it can be any widget here. Using basic Text for this example
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("Activity"),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CheckboxListTile(value: _isChecked, onChanged: (bool value){setState(() {
                      _isChecked = value;
                    });})
                  ],
                ),

                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CheckboxListTile(value: _isChecked, onChanged: (bool value){onChanged(value);},)
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),

            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CheckboxListTile(value: _isChecked, onChanged: (bool value){onChanged(value);})
                  ],
                ),

                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CheckboxListTile(value: _isChecked, onChanged: (bool value){onChanged(value);},)
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),//new Text("Hello!"),
        isActive: true),
    new Step(
        title: new Text("Step 2"),
        content: new Text("World!"),
        // You can change the style of the step icon i.e number, editing, etc.
        state: StepState.editing,
        isActive: true),
    new Step(
        title: new Text("Step 3"),
        content: new Text("Hello World!"),
        isActive: true),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      // Appbar
      appBar: new AppBar(
        // Title
        title: new Text("Simple Material App"),
      ),
      // Body
      body: new Container(
          child: new Stepper(
            // Using a variable here for handling the currentStep
            currentStep: this.current_step,
            // List the steps you would like to have
            steps: my_steps,
            // Define the type of Stepper style
            // StepperType.horizontal :  Horizontal Style
            // StepperType.vertical   :  Vertical Style
            type: StepperType.vertical,
            // Know the step that is tapped
            onStepTapped: (step) {
              // On hitting step itself, change the state and jump to that step
              setState(() {
                // update the variable handling the current step value
                // jump to the tapped step
                current_step = step;
              });
              // Log function call
              print("onStepTapped : " + step.toString());
            },
            onStepCancel: () {
              // On hitting cancel button, change the state
              setState(() {
                // update the variable handling the current step value
                // going back one step i.e subtracting 1, until its 0
                if (current_step > 0) {
                  current_step = current_step - 1;
                } else {
                  current_step = 0;
                }
              });
              // Log function call
              print("onStepCancel : " + current_step.toString());
            },
            // On hitting continue button, change the state
            onStepContinue: () {
              setState(() {
                // update the variable handling the current step value
                // going back one step i.e adding 1, until its the length of the step
                if (current_step < my_steps.length - 1) {
                  current_step = current_step + 1;
                } else {
                  current_step = 0;
                }
              });
              // Log function call
              print("onStepContinue : " + current_step.toString());
            },


          )),

    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you try to explain in details what is your problem exactly, what you try to achieve and what's the issue you face. Also your code won't work as it is (I've tested  it and it has rederbox errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your widget tree as a field of the class:

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  String parameter;

  Widget widget = Text(parameter); // only static members can be accessed in initializers
}
```

You shouldn't do this. You cannot initialize a field of an object with other class properties. Instead, create that widget inside the *build* method:

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  String parameter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget = Text(parameter);

    // TODO: do something width `widget`
  }  
}
```